# insertar en dos tablas al mismo tiempo

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla noticias y una tabla foto noticias es decir que una sola noticia puede tener muchas fotos

mi pregunta es como hacer una inserccion  por ejemplo una sola noticia tenga 5 fotos y de deben guardar al mismo tiempo la noticia y las fotos; ademas  quiera hacerlo dentro de una y transaccion 
quisiera saber si se puede y como

gracias

Comment: Sí se puede, y el cómo tendrías que dar más detalles para orientarte, lo vas a hacer directo en un script de SQL o en algún lenguaje de programación? puedes compartir tu código?

Comment: la idea es hacerlo en php entonces no se si se haría desde el motor de base de datos o desde el lenguaje de programación

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-begin-transaction.php

Comment: porque si se hace desde el lenguaje de programacion debo validar que si se guarde para poder recorrer donde estan las imágenes y guardarlas con el id de la noticia entonces eso es lo que no se como se valida que si se guardo satisfactoriamente

Comment: lee un poco sobre transacciones pero su naturaleza es eso precisamente, no tienes que validar nada

Comment: Claro que si puedes hacerlo, primero tienes que insertar la `noticia` para obtener el `id`, posteriormente insertas en la tabla `foto_noticia` con el `id` de la noticia para que puedas asociarlos. Especificamente lo estas haciendo en la base de datos, algún sp o en algún lenguaje de programación?